# how to set SliverAppBar Height to suit it's flexibleSpace content

Tags: flutter

i have the following simple code

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return

      NestedScrollView(
          headerSliverBuilder: (context,value){
            return[
              SliverAppBar(

              //  expandedHeight: ??,

                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,


                flexibleSpace:  FlexibleSpaceBar(
                    background: headWidget()

                ),


              )
            ];
          },

          body:   myWidget()
      );

  }
}
```

now how can i set the `SliverAppBar expandedHeight` to auto suit my `headWidget()` height

currently i use  `ScreenUtil` plugin to set `expandedHeight` manually but is there any other auto way ?

any idea ?

[image]